# Division two vectors

Tags: r, vector, division

I have first vector, example: `x=1:10` and second with prime numbers, example `y=c(2,3,5,7)`

And I want **sort** vector x: divisible by 2, divisible by 3, etc.
So, The output would look like this: `2 4 6 8 10 3 9 5 7`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `apply` loop and `mod`:

```
unique(unlist(sapply(y, function(i)x[x%%i == 0])))
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10  3  9  5  7
```

Or using `as.logical` instead of `==`, suggested by @ZheyuanLi:

```
unique(unlist(sapply(y, function(i) x[!as.logical(x%%i)])))
```

Similar approach using expand.grid instead of apply:

```
xy <- expand.grid(x, y)
unique(xy[ xy[,1]%%xy[,2] == 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
unique(rep(x, length(y))[rep(x, length(y))%% rep(y, each = length(x))==0])
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10  3  9  5  7
```